# Pass value of TextView on Click

Tags: android, textview

In my xml(activity_main.xml) there are 4 Textviews.

Textview textview1,textview2,textview3,textview4.

and there values are value1,value2,value3,value4.

In MainActivity.java
This is my onCreate and onClick Methods,

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv3.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv4.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
 String value;
}
```

I want to set value of Textview which has been clicked in my onClick method

ie, if user clicked on Textview1-----String value=value1

if user clicked on Textview2-----String value=value2

if user clicked on Textview3-----String value=value3

if user clicked on Textview4-----String value=value4

Can anyone please help me to get this.

Comment: Just use `String value = v.getText();` in your `onClick` method.

Answer (score 1):

Get view id as `v.getId()` in `onClick` method,so use

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
      case R.id.textView1:
       value = value1;
      break;
      case R.id.textView2:
      value = value2;
     break;
     case R.id.textView3:
      value = value3;
     break;
     case R.id.textView4:
      value = value4;
     break;
}
```

**Edit**

As Squonk suggested you may directly use `v.getText()` to  get values of textviews in `onClick` method as

```
public void onClick(View v) {
value = v.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

set tag in xml file in all textView

like

```
android:tag="value1"
```

for textView1

```
android:tag="value2"
```

for textView2

and get String

```
String value= v.getTag().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

In onClick(View v), you can use v.getId() to know the id of the view that has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try below code in `onClick()` method........

```
 public void onClick(View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.textView1:
            //your code;
       break;

    case R.id.textView2:
            //your code;
        break;

    case R.id.textView3:
            //your code;
        break;

    case R.id.textView4:
            //your code;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: you should write `TextView` id in CASE statement

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get names of textViews as"

```
String text1 = tv1.getText().toString();
String text2 = tv2.getText().toString();
...... so on..
```

Then do click action by using:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 if(v.getId() == R.id.textView1)
 { 
   DoSomething();
   return;
 }

 if(v.getId() == R.id.textView2)
 { 
   DoSomething2();
   return;
 }
```

....... so on...

Answer (score 0):

see this code : you will get the particular textview's value in the string "value" when click on particular textview.

```
 public class test extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

TextView tv1, tv2, tv3, tv4;
String value;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv2.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv3.setOnClickListener(this);
    tv4.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.textView1:
        value = tv1.getText().toString();
        break;
    case R.id.textView2:
        value = tv2.getText().toString();
        break;
    case R.id.textView3:
        value = tv3.getText().toString();
        break;
    case R.id.textView4:
        value = tv4.getText().toString();
        break;

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**When you do various action each TextView click(without implementing OnClickListener) try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tv4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // write your TextView 1 click listener code here
            }
        });
        tv2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // write your TextView 2 click listener code here
            }
        });
        tv3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // write your TextView 2 click listener code here
            }
        });
        tv4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // write your TextView 4 click listener code here
            }
        });
}
```